Transferring the signal spectrum to a given area
I have already asked this question and received an answer in this thread. But now, studying in more detail, I am confused by some contradictory information.
If you look at this topic. For shift down I multiply the input signal by $e^{-jw_ct}=cos(2 \pi f_c t)-jsin(2 \pi f_c t)$. To shift up I multiply the input signal by $e^{jw_ct}=cos(2 \pi f_c t)+jsin(2 \pi f_c t)$. In this regard, in this topic $e^{-jw_ct}=cos(2 \pi f_c t)+jsin(2 \pi f_c t)$.
If I understand correctly, in order to shift a signal that is in the 5500-6500Hz band to the 0-1000Hz band, I should do this:

$s_n e^{-jw_ct}=s_ncos(2 \pi 6/48)$ and $s_n(-sin(2 \pi 6/48))$
I pass the resulting sine and cosine components through a 10th order digital low-pass filter with a cutoff frequency of 500 Hz.
Next, to shift the signal up to the 0-1000Hz band I need, I multiply the sine and cosine components by $e^{jw_ct}$ and take only the real part. $s_{ncos}cos(2 \pi 0.5/48)+s_{nsin}sin(2 \pi 0.5/48)$. This follows from the formula described in this post.

Am I doing everything right? In general it works, but I have a number of questions and things that are unclear to me...

I originally have a sampling frequency of 48 kHz. When I moved the signal to the 0-1000 Hz band, can I decimate it by a factor of 24 to 2 kHz? Since I know I shouldn't have a signal above the 1 kHz band.
Initially, my signal comes from a microwave module, such as IVS-979. I set the signal deviation to 3.5 m (I use a sawtooth signal with a frequency of 1 kHz as a modulating signal). If I look at the spectrum at a frequency of 11.5 kHz-12.5 kHz (which is equivalent to 42 m), but there is movement (a car is driving crosswise) at a distance of 60-70 m I see a signal in the band of 11.5 kHz-12.5 kHz, but it should be at a frequency of ~ 17-20 kHz. At the same time, at a distance of 0-42 m, everything works correctly. I tried to supply a sinusoidal signal from the generator (instead of the microwave module) and everything also works correctly.

